# element.onclick not doesn't call function when element is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a Modal dynamically. I want to make some buttons in this modal to open a `SubModal`. The buttons show up in html, but clicking these buttons does nothing.
Here is my code.

```
const subtaskList = document.getElementById('subtaskList');
for (const subtaskIndex in task.subtasks) {
    const subtaskButton = document.createElement('button');
    subtaskButton.classList.add('taskModalSubtaskButton');
    subtaskButton.onclick = () => {
        openSubTaskModal(task.subtasks[subtaskIndex], task);
    }
    subtaskButton.innerText = task.subtasks[subtaskIndex].name;
    subtaskList.appendChild(subtaskButton);
    subtaskList.innerHTML += '<br>';
}
```

While troubleshooting I made an array to hold the buttons and used console.log() to see its elements. They all had the `onclick` function. I've clicked the buttons from the dev console by getting their class name and nothing, so I know it's not a display issue. I feel like I am misunderstanding something and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `subtaskList.innerHTML += '<br>';` it is good idea to use `subtaskList.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));` instead.

Here is working snippet:

```js
function doSomething(url) {
    alert(url);
}

const subtaskList = document.getElementById('subtaskList');
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const subtaskButton = document.createElement('button');
    subtaskButton.classList.add('taskModalSubtaskButton');

    subtaskButton.innerText = "name" + i;

    subtaskButton.onclick = (function (url) {
                return function () {
                    doSomething(url);
                };
            })("URL #" + i)

    subtaskList.appendChild(subtaskButton);
    subtaskList.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
```

```html
<div id="subtaskList"></div>
```

Also I change a bit `onclick` function to send correspond index to `doSomething` function